# HTML frames problem with a grafana dashboard

Tags: html, grafana, frames

I need help to complete one of my projects where I have had a problem for over 6 months.

A summary of the project and the problem :

It is a display server with a Raspberry Pi 4 card. I want to display two pages of HTML on one screen. The first page is a PRTG supervision card in HTTPS. The second one is a dashboard Grafana in HTTP. To do this, I decided to use a frames HTML with the two links. But for the Grafana dashboard, Firefox returns me an error "Firefox cannot open this page" and the second page works normally.

Things I've already tried :

- Use X-Frames options in the Grafana settings and the apache server.
- Change the links in HTTPS with the SSL certificates.

I hope I have been as understanding as possible and that you can help me with this project.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to open your page with another browser (Chrome, Safari)?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment.                                                                                 Chrome : "IP does not allow connection"                                                                           Edge : "IP refused the connection"                                                                                           IE : "This content cannot be displayed in a frame"